# JSON: building JSON data before json_encode

Tags: php, json

Hi I am very poor at building JSON data as I wanted to understand JSON better. I have read JSON.org but it is very limited in information. Therefore I have poor understanding JSON. However I am closer to getting the result.

```
$data = array('title'=>'JSON Sample Data',
'items'=> array('name' => 'text','value' => 'text date'),
('name' => 'integer','value' => 100),
('name' => 'float','value' => 5.65),
('name' => 'boolean','value' =>false)
);

$output = json_encode($data);
print_r ($output);
echo $output;
```

So I got error here and I do not have any idea what went wrong with JSON structure.

Comment: Your `$data` is syntax incorrect. You're missing some `array` keywords there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building it wrong (syntax error - missing `array` keywords):

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'JSON Sample Data',
    'items' => array(
        array('name' => 'text','value' => 'text date'),
        array('name' => 'integer','value' => 100),
        array('name' => 'float','value' => 5.65),
        array('name' => 'boolean','value' =>false),
        ),
    );
```

Good indentation goes you a long way. :)

Comment: Hi Thanks  I am sorry If I had put up my answer earlier. Your help  is correct. Thanks